# Open id authorization error when logging into google

Tags: objective-c, google-calendar-api, openid, macos-sierra, google-signin

Getting this error when logging into google

Error Domain=org.openid.appauth.general Code=-4 "The HTTP listener was cancelled programmatically." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The HTTP listener was cancelled programmatically.}

```
OIDServiceConfiguration *configuration =
    [GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization configurationForGoogle];
    NSArray<NSString *> *scopes = @[ kGTLRAuthScopeCalendar, OIDScopeEmail ];

OIDAuthorizationRequest *request =
[[OIDAuthorizationRequest alloc] initWithConfiguration:configuration
                                              clientId:kClientID
                                          clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                                scopes:scopes
                                           redirectURL:localRedirectURI
                                          responseType:OIDResponseTypeCode
                                  additionalParameters:nil];
redirectHTTPHandler.currentAuthorizationFlow =
    [OIDAuthState authStateByPresentingAuthorizationRequest:request
                                                   callback:^(OIDAuthState *_Nullable authState,
                                                              NSError *_Nullable error)
    {
//here i get nil authstate and error
}
```

Can anyone please explain me the causes and possible solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this is that your `redirectHTTPHandler` is being released from memory before the callback occurs. Looking at the source for `AppAuth`, which appears to be [here](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/blob/master/Source/macOS/OIDRedirectHTTPHandler.m), shows that the http listener gets cancelled programmatically when the handler is deallocated.

You can fix this by making your `redirectHTTPHandler` a member of your class, not just declared in the same scope as the instantiation of your `OIDAuthorizationRequest`. This will guarantee that your `redirectHTTPHandler` doesn't get deallocated before the callback happens.